# How to add a shortcode to a theme automatically when plugin install

Tags: wordpress, plugins

How can i insert a  plugin shortcode to template file automatically when install the plugin

Comment: Are you trying to add it to a template file or the content of a page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute your shortcode via an action hook. It looks like appthemes has a number of them provided [here](http://docs.appthemes.com/action-hooks/)

Look to see if there is an action hook within the div where you want to display your shortcode.

This example will execute your shortcode after the post.

```
<?php
function my_awesome_shortcode() { 
    echo do_shortcode('[name_of_shortcode]');
} 
add_action( 'appthemes_after_post', 'my_awesome_shortcode' ); 
?>
```

Comment: Is there any way to add shortcode inside the Ad Categories listing section

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Put this code in your plugin main file.

```
/* This function runs when plugin is activated */
function myplugin_activate() {
    add_shortcode( 'footag', 'footag_func' );
}

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

/* Function to register shortcode */
function footag_func( $atts ) {
    return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
```

To learn more you can refer [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) and [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode)

Comment: i already create shortcode and its working fine, but i need to display the content  without using the shortcode in a specific div in the template file

Comment: i'm working on a A-to-Z category listing plugin for appthemes, like WP Alphabet Listing Plugin, i need to display the category list without call the shortcode